# Why is my Azure function returning text/plain from FileContentResult?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have some C# in an MVC application that works and is:

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> LoadImage()
{
   <code here>
   return File(imageBytes, imageType);
}
```

When I call a URL I am shown an image in the browser.

I am porting this to an Azure function and see that File no longer exists so do this instead:

```
[Function("LoadImage")]
public async Task<FileContentResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    <code here>
    return new FileContentResult(imageBytes, imageType);
}
```

Looking in Postman I get a JSON response with a header of text/plain, transfer-encoding chunked.

How can I get the Azure function to render the image rather than return JSON?

I've also tried IActionResult with the below but get the same issue of JSON/text/plain header returned.

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new ByteArrayContent(imageBytes)
};
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(imageType);
```

> {
> "FileContents": "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",
> "ContentType": "image/png",
> "FileDownloadName": "",
> "LastModified": null,
> "EntityTag": null,
> "EnableRangeProcessing": false
> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return an `HttpResponseData` object created via `req.CreateResponse(...)` which has a `Body` class of type `Stream` to write a stream to the response or use the `WriteByteAsync` extension method to write a byte array.  I suggest your read the documentation.  An example:

```
var response = req.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.Ok );

// byte array
await response.WriteBytesAsync( byteArrayToReturn );
// OR stream
response.Body = streamToReturn;
// OR JSON, for completeness
await response.WriteAsJsonAsync( yourObjectToReturnAsJson );

// access to headers and cookies via properties
response.Headers.Add( ... );

return response;
```

Create extension methods for reusing common code scenarios.  For example, to replace `FileContentResult( imageBytes, imageType )`:

```
public static HttpResponseData WriteBytesWithContentTypeAsync( 
    this HttpResponseData response, 
    byte[] data, 
    string contentType )
{
    await response.WriteBytesAsync( data );
    response.Headers.Add( "Content-Type", imageType );

    return response;
}
```

then use:

```
return await req.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.Ok )
    .WriteBytesWithContentTypeAsync( imageBytes, imageType );
```